# How to test ManagedBean using Arquillian?

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian

All my managedBean classes uses CDI. I have the following managedBean which I'd like to test. As you can see, there are several EJB and managedBean in the properties. I think that this is the root cause of the problem.

```
package pa.cka.ge

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class UserBean{
   ...
   some properties
   ...

   @EJB
   private someDao dao1

   @EJB
   private anotherDao dao2

   ...

   @EJB
   private DaoNumerN daoN

   @ManagedProperty=(value="#{managedBeanName}")
   private ManagedBeanName mbn1;

   ...

   @ManagedProperty=(value="#{managedBeanNameN}")
   private ManagedBeanName mbnN;

   ...
   some methods
   ...

   ...
   getters and setters
   ...
}
```

My idea was to use Arquillian to test the class above because It has several methods whose variables are initialized in init() method and If I used PowerMock, I should copy init() text in before(), make testing too high coupled to implementation. Moroever, there are methods which are very difficult to call without a managed container (I should mock the universe). My Arquillian class test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class DichiarazioneUserBeanTest {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{dichiarazioneUserBean}") //also tried with @Inject
    private DeclarationUserBean dub;


    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addPackage(MyJPAEntity.class.getPackage())
                .addClasses(ManagadeBeanName1.class, dao1.class, dao2.class)
                .addClasses(dao3.class, dao4.class)
                .addClasses(dao5.class, ManagedBeanName2.class, ManagedBeanName3.class)
                .addClass(ManagedBeanName4.class)
                .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        System.out.println(jar.toString(true));
        return jar;
    }

    public byte[] extractBytes (String ImageName) throws IOException {
        // open image
        File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

        // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
        WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
        DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

        return ( data.getData() );
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException{
        dub.setProperty(null); //here I get java.lang.NullPointerException
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){

    }

}
```

I have also tried using @Inject notation for ManagedBean and @EJB notation for EJB but it didn't work

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class DichiarazioneUserBeanTest {

    @Inject
    private DeclarationUserBean dub;

    ...

    @EJB
    private Dao dao1

    ....


    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addPackage(MyJPAEntity.class.getPackage())
                .addClasses(ManagadeBeanName1.class, dao1.class, dao2.class)
                .addClasses(dao3.class, dao4.class)
                .addClasses(dao5.class, ManagedBeanName2.class, ManagedBeanName3.class)
                .addClass(ManagedBeanName4.class)
                .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        System.out.println(jar.toString(true));
        return jar;
    }

    public byte[] extractBytes (String ImageName) throws IOException {
        // open image
        File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

        // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
        WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
        DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

        return ( data.getData() );
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException{
        dub.setProperty(null); //here I get java.lang.NullPointerException
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean Mock and PowerMock? Yes

Comment: Sry I did not understand your question correct forget my comment.

Comment: Do you mean I should Inject EJBs in the managedProperty using PowerMock (@InjectMocks)? Or maybe are you suggesting me to give up integration testing for unit testing?